# How to print report from website in odoo11?

Tags: odoo-11

I want to print report by clicking on print button on website.

But it shows some error:

> File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 829, in dispatch
>       r = self._call_function(**self.params)
>     File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
>       return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
>       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
>       result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
>     File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 936, in **call**
>       return self.method(*args, **kw)
>     File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
>       response = f(*args, **kw)
>     File "/home/priya/repo/rp-group/rpg_quotation/controllers/web_page.py", line 1442, in update_quotation
>       res = self.print_quotation_software_report(data, int(quotation_id))
>     File "/home/priya/repo/rp-group/rpg_quotation/controllers/web_page.py", line 2699, in print_quotation_software_report
>       pdf = request.env.ref('rpg_quotation.rpg_quotation_software_setwise__report').report_action(self, data=data, config=False)
>     File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py", line 703, in report_action
>       context = dict(self.env.context, active_ids=active_ids)

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'active_ids' referenced before assignment
```

My js code:

```js
$(document).on('click', Quotation.elements.print_quotation_software_selector, function() {
 var self = $(this);
 var data = {
   'xpath': null,
   'cmd': 'print_quotation_software_report'
 };
 Quotation.methods.xhr(data, function(r) {
 });

});
```

My Python code:

```py
def print_quotation_software_report(self,data,quotation_id):
 order_id = quotation_id
 if quotation_id:
   pdf = request.env.ref('rpg_quotation.rpg_quotation_software_setwise__report').report_action(self, data=data, config=False)
   pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf))]
   return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
```

Here,

`rpg_quotation` is the module name and `rpg_quotation_software_setwise__report` is report id.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Printed the report by giving a href to the button like this,

```
<a t-attf-href="'/report/pdf/account.report_invoice/%s' % i.id">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md o_website_form_send">Print Invoice</button>
```

In the i.id i have the id of the invoice.
This is the format,
report/type_of_the_report/module_name.template_name/id

To print the report from the  controller,

```
@http.route('/school/card', methods=['POST', 'GET'], csrf=False, type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def print_id(self, **kw):
    student_id = kw['stud_id']
    if student_id:
        pdf = request.env['report'].sudo().get_pdf([student_id], 'module_name.report_name', data=None)
        pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf))]
        return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
    else:
        return request.redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are passing self as the value for docids positional argument for the `report_action` method call instead of `quotation_id` to remove your actual error.

But that `report_action` method call will not return the pdf file data. You will need to change it to:

```py
pdf = request.env.ref('rpg_quotation.rpg_quotation_software_setwise__report').sudo().render_qweb_pdf([quotation_id])[0]
```

See an example at:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/b29b545fe8464610ce04ac8be11e0356962d10d9/addons/sale/controllers/portal.py#L196

Comment: My Xml code:    
<a t-attf-href= "'/report/pdf/rpg_quotation.rpg_quotation_software_set_report/rpg_quotation_software_setwise__report'">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn green" id="print_quotation_software" style="display:none;" data-translate="print_report">Print Report</button>
                    </a>

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide you a solution to the render of the pdf

Comment: File "/home/priya/repo/rp-group/rpg_quotation/controllers/web_page.py", line 2700, in print_quotation_software_report
    pdf, _ = request.env.ref('rpg_quotation.rpg_quotation_software_setwise__report').sudo().render_qweb_pdf([order_id])[0]

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: If i write python code as :

def print_quotation_software_report(self,data,quotation_id):
        order_id = quotation_id

        if order_id:
            pdf, _ = request.env.ref('rpg_quotation.rpg_quotation_software_setwise__report').sudo().render_qweb_pdf([order_id])
            pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', u'%s' % len(pdf))]
            return json.dumps({'pdf': pdf, 'pdfhttpheaders':pdfhttpheaders})
        else:
            return request.redirect('/')

Then error comes:

Comment: 2018-10-17 12:15:28,662 10814 INFO RP_19_9 odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /home/priya/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/RP_19_9/57/57d4fef2c45d2462337a4e8f2c63d82b6e064d85
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priya/workspace/ODOO11/odoo-11.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 101, in _file_read
    r = base64.b64encode(open(full_path,'rb').read())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/priya/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/RP_19_9/57/57d4fef2c45d2462337a4e8f2c63d82b6e064d85'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 334: invalid start byte

Comment: You should check the provided Odoo example and stick to it

Comment: You will have to debug it or add logs to see the return values of the render_qweb_pdf and other lines